# Como personalizo um Navbar somente quando ele estiver "collapsed" com bootstrap 4?

Tags: css, bootstrap

Eu tenho o seguinte código:

```
<!-- Navigation Bar -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light navperson">
    <!-- Brand -->
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img class="img-fluid logo" src="imagens/bonfireicon.png"></a>
    <!-- Hide Button -->
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#nav-content"
    aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toogle Navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <!-- NavBar Content -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="nav-content">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link hvr-sweep-to-right" href="#">
                    <span class="fa-stack">
                        <span class="fa fa-square-o fa-stack-2x"></span>
                        <span class="fa fa-home fa-stack-1x"></span>
                    </span>
                    Home
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link hvr-sweep-to-right" href="#">
                    <span class="fa-stack">
                        <span class="fa fa-square-o fa-stack-2x"></span>
                        <span class="fa fa-flask fa-stack-1x"></span> 
                    </span>
                    Estus Flasks
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link hvr-sweep-to-right" href="#">
                    <span class="fa-stack">
                        <span class="fa fa-square-o fa-stack-2x"></span>
                        <span class="fa fa-bomb fa-stack-1x"></span>
                    </span>
                    Capra Demon
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link hvr-sweep-to-right" href="#">
                    <span class="fa-stack">
                        <span class="fa fa-square-o fa-stack-2x"></span>
                        <span class="fa fa-ravelry fa-stack-1x"></span>
                    </span>
                    Areas
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link hvr-sweep-to-right" href="#">
                    <span class="fa-stack">
                        <span class="fa fa-square-o fa-stack-2x"></span>
                        <span class="fa fa-shield fa-stack-1x"></span>
                    </span>
                    Legendary Items
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <!--Login Button Triggers Modal-->
        <form class="form-inline my-2 my my-lg-0">
            <button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-login" class="btn btn-outline-info">Logar</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Este código faz com que crie uma navbar parecida com esta:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A função toggler do bootstrap faz com que ela fique assim em um celular/tablet:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que eu quero? Trabalhar com a div quando ela estiver na forma "toggled", eu quero manipular a aparência dela **somente** quando ela estiver visualizando no celular por exemplo, porque quando eu vou alterar as propriedades no css, acaba alterando também quando ela não está "collapsed" ou em tela cheia.

Eu quero melhorar a usabilidade fazendo com que o menu da navbar preencha a tela toda do celular, e não somente no cantinho esquerdo, de forma que aumente o campo de seleção para atingir o conteúdo desejado.

Comment: Na documentação https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/ ctrl+f "class prefix". Voce pode configurar as divs para tamanhos de telas especificos. Talvez te ajude

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para isso você deverá tornar seu site responsivo introduzindo o uso de @media para configurar a aparência do site em função do tipo de dispositivo utilizado ao acessá-lo.

Basicamente, você pode configurar da seguinte forma:

1) Para estilos aplicáveis ao site acessado em resolução igual ou superior a 700px (do seu computador por exemplo):

```
@media screen and (min-width: 769px){
}
```

2) Para dispositivos menores:

```
@media all and (max-width: 768px){
}
```

A propriedade "min-width" determina que o estilo será aplicado quando a resolução da tela tiver dentro do limite especificado.

Existem várias outras opções de configuração da tag @media que poderão ser muitos úteis também. Visite depois o link abaixo.

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Answer (score 0):

Finalmente consegui obter o resultado desejado com a dica do @Caiuby Freitas. Agora o item da lista (link) da nav está preenchendo a linha toda para facilitar o acesso em dispositivos menores.

[image]

```
@media all and (max-width: 765px) {

.nav-cel {
    display: inline-grid;
}}
```